# The header name "headers" is not set in the GET request processing declaration

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I'm trying to set the name of the header in the model description, but it remains empty in the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
@router.get('/hash_header',response_model=models.hash_out,tags=["use-hash"],responses={
        200: {
            "model": models.hash_out,
            "description": "Return has code",
            "headers": [
                {'name':"Secret-Code","description":"Secret code","type":"string"}
            ]
        }        
})
```

In the docs:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headers` should [be a dictionary with the name as a key](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#headerObject), not a list:

```py
@router.get('/hash_header',response_model=models.hash_out,tags=["use-hash"],responses={
    200: {
        "model": models.hash_out,
        "description": "Return has code",
        "headers": {
            "Secret-Code": {"description":"Secret code","type":"string"}
        }
    }        
})
```